# LINQ grouping in object

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have two classes

```
public class MyObjects{
  public bool Active {get; set;}
  public List<OtherObject> OtherObjects {get; set;}
}

public class OtherObject {
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public bool Enabled {get; set;}
  public string Address {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

My current result is

```
MyObject { Active = true; }, 
OtherObjects: [OtherObject: { Id: 1, Name: 'First'}, 
OtherObject{Id: 2, Name: 'First'}, 
OtherObject{Id: 3, Name: 'Second'}];
```

I want to group them by `Name` so I would still have `Active` property and those `OtherObjects` inside would be grouped by `OtherObject` `Name` property. Is it possible to do so only using LINQ?

**EDIT:**
Final result should be json, that I will use in angular, so it should be something like this:

```
{
  ""Active"": true,
  ""OtherObjects"": [
    {
      ""ObjectName"": ""Second"",
      ""ObjectOtherProperties"": [
        {
          ""Id"": 1,
          ""Enabled"": false
        },
        {
          ""Id"": 2,
          ""Enabled"": true
        }
      ],
      ""ObjectName"": ""Second"",
      ""ObjectOtherProperties"": [
        {
          ""Id"": 1,
          ""Enabled"": false
        }
      ],
    ]
  }
}
```

Any suggestions how to achieve this? Maybe I must make other classes and somehow map them by grouping?

Comment: It's very unclear to me what the result would look like, I'm afraid - the "my current result" part is sort of JSON but not quite... it would be *much* easier to help you with a short but complete example. LINQ's `GroupBy` is very likely to be what you want, but it's hard to tell at the moment.

Comment: yes, I would like to have a JSON at the end, but I don't know how to explain it clearly. I'll try to update somehow to show result, that I want to have at the end

Comment: `I want to group them by Name` There is no name property in `MyObjects`, only in `OtherObjects` (which you are grouping in the child collection). Could you give us the exact model you have and the one you want? Some of the properties don't match up (name vs objectname), etc. There's currently a lot of guess work for us to do to figure out a solution

Comment: Question seems unclear, can you provide exact data model and required output json structure

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it, keeping it simple:

```
// 1. Add OtherObjectsDictionary
// 2. Block OtherObjects in the json serialization
public class MyObjects
{

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
    public List<OtherObject> OtherObjects { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, List<OtherObject>> OtherObjectsDictionary { get; set; }

}

// 3. Block Name in the json serialization
public class OtherObject
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

// 4. Linq queries to achieve the grouped result
// 5. Serialize to Json
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var myObjects = new MyObjects() { Active = true, OtherObjects = new List<OtherObject>() };
    myObjects.OtherObjects.Add(new OtherObject { Id = 1, Name = "First" });
    myObjects.OtherObjects.Add(new OtherObject { Id = 2, Name = "First" });
    myObjects.OtherObjects.Add(new OtherObject { Id = 3, Name = "Second" });

    myObjects.OtherObjectsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<OtherObject>>();
    var distinctNames = myObjects.OtherObjects.Select(otherObject => otherObject.Name).Distinct();
    foreach(var distinctName in distinctNames)
    {
        var groupedObjectsList = myObjects.OtherObjects.Where(otherObject => otherObject.Name == distinctName).ToList();
        myObjects.OtherObjectsDictionary.Add(distinctName, groupedObjectsList);
    }

    var outputJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObjects);

}
```

This is the json result:

```
{
  "Active": true,
  "OtherObjectsDictionary": {
    "First": [
      {
        "Id": 1,
        "Enabled": false,
        "Address": null
      },
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "Enabled": false,
        "Address": null
      }
    ],
    "Second": [
      {
        "Id": 3,
        "Enabled": false,
        "Address": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the System.Web.Extensions .dll as Add References for framework 4.0 projects (not 4.0 Client Profile).

[image]

Then add using inside your class.
[image]

I also applied a different approach, a more-or-less DB like normalization.

List of classes

```
        public class MyObjects
        {
            public bool Active { get; set; }
            public List<ObjectName> OtherObjects { get; set; }
        }

        public class ObjectName
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public List<OtherObject> OtherObjectProperties { get; set; }
        }

        public class OtherObject
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public bool Enabled { get; set; }
            [ScriptIgnore]
            public string Address { get; set; }
            [ScriptIgnore]
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

populate the records..

```
            List<OtherObject> oList = new List<OtherObject>();
            oList.Add(new OtherObject() { Id = 2, Name = "First" });
            oList.Add(new OtherObject() { Id = 3, Name = "Second" });

            // each name with objects
            List<ObjectName> oNames = new List<ObjectName>();
            oNames.AddRange(oList.Select(p => new ObjectName() { 
                   Name = p.Name
                   , OtherObjectProperties = oList.Where(p1 => p1.Name == p.Name).ToList()
            }).Distinct()
            );

            // parent object with with object names
            MyObjects mo = new MyObjects() { Active = true, OtherObjects = oNames };
```

and finally, the javascript serializer..

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string b = jss.Serialize(mo);
```

string b should give you the output like below..

```
{
"Active":true
,"OtherObjects":[
{
    "Name":"First"
    ,"OtherObjectProperties":[
    {
        "Id":2
        ,"Enabled":false}
    ]},
    {
    "Name":"Second"
    ,"OtherObjectProperties":[
    {
        "Id":3
        ,"Enabled":false}
    ]
}]
}
```

Please advise if you're confused about any of the following.. :)